# Calculating population standard deviation

Tags: python, statistics

This is a script I have written to calculate the population standard deviation. I feel that this can be simplified and also be made more pythonic.

```
from math import sqrt

def mean(lst):
    """calculates mean"""
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        sum += lst[i]
    return (sum / len(lst))

def stddev(lst):
    """calculates standard deviation"""
    sum = 0
    mn = mean(lst)
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        sum += pow((lst[i]-mn),2)
    return sqrt(sum/len(lst)-1)

numbers = [120,112,131,211,312,90]

print stddev(numbers)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way to make `mean()` more pythonic is to use the `sum()` built-in function.

```
def mean(lst):
    return sum(lst) / len(lst)
```

Concerning your loops on lists, you don't need to use `range()`. This is enough:

```
for e in lst:
   sum += e
```

Other comments:

- You don't need parentheses around the return value (check out [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) when you have a doubt about this).
- Your docstrings are useless: it's obvious from the name that it calculates the mean. At least make them more informative ("returns the mean of lst").
- Why do you use "-1" in the return for stddev? Is that a bug?
- You are computing the standard deviation using the variance: call that "variance", not sum!
- You should type pow(e-mn,2), not pow((e-mn),2). Using parentheses inside a function call could make the reader think he's reading a tuple (eg. pow((e,mn),2) is valid syntax)
- You shouldn't use pow() anyway, ** is enough.

This would give:

```
def stddev(lst):
    """returns the standard deviation of lst"""
    variance = 0
    mn = mean(lst)
    for e in lst:
        variance += (e-mn)**2
    variance /= len(lst)

    return sqrt(variance)
```

It's still way too verbose! Since we're handling lists, why not using list comprehensions?

```
def stddev(lst):
    """returns the standard deviation of lst"""
    mn = mean(lst)
    variance = sum([(e-mn)**2 for e in lst]) / len(lst)
    return sqrt(variance)
```

This is not perfect. You could add tests using [doctest](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html). Obviously, you should not code those functions yourself, except in a small project. Consider using Numpy for a bigger project.

Comment: Thank you Cygal for your answer. I realize things like tests and validation need to be added, but I think you put me in the right direction.

Comment: @mad, I realize you're not able to comment due to your reputation, but if you see a problem in a post and want to fix it, you'll either have to be patient and wait until you have 50 reputation or go out, answer a question, and get five upvotes (or ask a good question and get 10). Please don't try to circumvent the system. Third-party edits should only edit the content of the post (as opposed to formatting, grammar, spelling, pasting in content from links etc.) with explicit approval from the poster.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to divide the variance by N before taking the sqrt in the last/least verbose example.

Comment: @CodyA.Ray Your Rev 2 corrected the result, but it was not the [right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Discrete_random_variable) fix.

Comment: @200_success can you elaborate? Yeah, variance is the wrong variable name there. I could've just divided in the "return" line. But the equation seems correct for non-sampled std dev: http://libweb.surrey.ac.uk/library/skills/Number%20Skills%20Leicester/page_19.htm

Comment: @CodyA.Ray See Rev 3. By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance), "variance" is the expected squared deviation from the mean. It is therefore important to put the division in the right place.

Comment: @Quentin Pradet the -1 is a compensation factor to deal with outliers. To see the difference between stdev on sample space vs population: https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/measures-of-spread-standard-deviation.php

Answer (score 6):

You have some serious calculation errors…

---

Assuming that this is Python 2, you also have bugs in the use of division: if both operands of `/` are integers, then Python 2 performs integer division.  Possible remedies are:

- [`from __future__ import division`](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)
- Cast one of the operands to a `float`: `return (float(sum)) / len(lst)`, for example.

(Assuming that this is Python 3, you can just use [`statistics.stdev()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.stdev).

---

The formula for the sample standard deviation is

$$ s = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ (x_i - \bar{x})^2}{n - 1}}$$

In `return sqrt(sum/len(lst)-1)`, you have an error with the precedence of operations.  It should be

```
return sqrt(float(sum) / (len(lst) - 1))
```

Comment: Source for formula?

Comment: @Agostino It's basically [common knowledge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Corrected_sample_standard_deviation) in statistics.